# Save input field in Thymeleaf to Set<>

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I would like to save the inputs to the Set interface. I have class Client.java:

```
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Address> shippingAddresses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Class ShippingAddress.java:

```
@Table(name = "address")
public class ShippingAddress {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
Long id;

String street;

String zip;
}
```

And it's my create form:

```
<form th:action="@{/add}" method="post" th:object="${client}">
            <tr>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{shippingAddress.street}"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{shippingAddress.zip}"/></td>
            </tr>
```

It works fine, but I can only save one street and one zip. I tried to improve it in this way to be able to save more data:

```
<form th:action="@{/add}" method="post" th:object="${client}">
            <tr>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{shippingAddress[0].street}"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{shippingAddress[0].zip}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{shippingAddress[1].street}"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{shippingAddress[1].zip}"/></td>
            </tr>
```

But I get information:

> Invalid property 'shippingAddress[0]' of bean class [model.Client]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'shippingAddress[0]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Set nor a Map; returned value was [ShippingAddress(id=null, street=null, zip=null, state=null, city=null, country=null)]

To add values to Set I should use the add method? But how to implement it with Thymeleaf?

Method in Controller (save data):

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveClient(@ModelAttribute Client client) {
    clientRepository.save(client);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Method in Controller (open create form)

```
    @RequestMapping("/create")
public String newClient(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("client", new Client());

    return "create";
}
```

Comment: The controller code may explain more. You have only showed here the Hibernate code, but you may have a problem in sending this data to the view in the controller itself.

Comment: I added the above method from the controller which saves the data. The problem here occurs when I open the form page - it gives an error in the browser "Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (create: 131)". I do not send data because I do not have a view.

Comment: And the form page controller?? The page that renders the Thymeleaf view, where its controller?

Comment: I added the above method in the controller which open the form page.

Comment: When tried to reproduce your error. Found `Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`, this means you may need a getter. Added this `public Set<String> getShippingAddresses() {
 return shippingAddresses;
}` and the problem changed, to "empty set", you could check in the template whether it is empty or no,    and you can also try not to create a new Client model manually in the controller, this may prevent you from making the validation and something returns to itself (like adding subitems). You can make `Client client` as a parameter to the controller.

Comment: Unfortunately, the message is still the same. I used:  `public Set<Address> getShippingAddresses() {return shippingAddresses;}` I have changed the parameter to Client client in method. I use Lombok to generate getters, etc.

Comment: I don't think `Set<entityClass>` is supported by Thymeleaf, only `List<entityClass>`.

Comment: Spring uses getters and setters to bind the object which it cant by using indices with a Set. Try Custom Getters/Setters like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28505620/8068435) or use a List.

Comment: Now in Client.java I have: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Address> getShippingAddress() {
        return shippingAddresses;
    }
    public void setShippingAddress(Set<ShippingAddress> shippingAddresses) {
        this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
    }
    public List<Address> getShippingAddressesAsList() {
        return new ArrayList<Address>(shippingAddresses);
    }`. I'm trying to save `<td><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{shippingAddress[0].street}"/></td>` (for now without using a loop) Cant get index 0.