# Cannot get element with index 2 from Set of size 2

Tags: java, spring

First of all sorry if I have faults on my text, im low with English.
I have a Table in a JSP that shows me people that is working on a patent.

Here you have the JSP code.

```
<c:forEach items="${newitem.inventors}" var="inv" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].toDelete"/>' class="toDelete" value=''/>
                        <input type="hidden" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].id"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.id}"/>'/> 
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].nom"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.nom}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].nif"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.nif}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].departament"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.departament}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].entitat"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.entitat}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].relacioLaboral"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.relacioLaboral}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].percent"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.percent}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td class="inventorCheckBox">
                              <input type="checkbox"/> 
                              <input type="hidden" class="textCheckBox" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].responsable"/>'  value='<c:out value="${inv.responsable}"/>' /> 
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].mail"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.mail}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].ordenacio"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.ordenacio}"/>'/> </td>
                        <td><span onclick="deleteInventor(this);" style="margin-left:15px;font-size:1.4em;cursor:pointer;" aria-hidden="true" class="colorLogo icon-close"></span></td>
                        <!--<td class="inventorCheckBox">
                                <input type="checkbox"/> 
                                <input type="hidden"  class="textCheckBox" name='<c:out value="inventors[${status.index}].intern"/>' value='<c:out value="${inv.intern}"/>'/> 
                        </td> -->
                    </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Now im implementing the funcionality to ADD more people. Those people is stored on a HashSet to later introduce the data to the DataBase. 
First of all im trying to add people just copying 1 row with the element inspector and saving, but when I click to save it throws me this error.

```
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [pinney] en el contexto con ruta [/ideas] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'inventors[2]' of bean class [com.gmv.pinney.vo.invencio.NovaInvencio]: Illegal attempt to get property 'inventors' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'inventors[2]' of bean class [com.gmv.pinney.vo.invencio.NovaInvencio]: Cannot get element with index 2 from Set of size 2, accessed using property path 'inventors[2]'] con causa raíz
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'inventors[2]' of bean class [com.gmv.pinney.vo.invencio.NovaInvencio]: Cannot get element with index 2 from Set of size 2, accessed using property path 'inventors[2]'
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:806)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:917)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:749)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.BaseCommandController.bindAndValidate(BaseCommandController.java:394)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:266)
    at com.gmv.pinney.web.forms.AbstractPinneyFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractPinneyFormController.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know what I've to do so, could you help me?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: arrays are 0-based

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save many objects in a spring <form:form>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498216/how-to-save-many-objects-in-a-spring-formform)

Comment: Quoting the possible duplicate: "The elements of a Set cannot be accessed by index. You will need to add methods which return a List wrapping your set."