# How to bind list of lists in spring MVC with jstl?

Tags: spring-mvc, binding, jstl

I am trying to bing List of Lists in spring MVC 
is it possible?
Do we need to write any custom binding methods?
Please help me.

JSTL Code :

```
 <input id="labelDTOS0.labelItemDTOS0.newValue" 
 name="labelDTOS[0].labelItemDTOS[0].newValue" type="text" value=""/>
```

DTOs:

```
public class LabelDTO {
public long id;
public String name;
public List<LabelItemDTO> labelItemDTOS;
}

public class LabelItemDTO {
public String value;
public String placeHolder;
public String newValue;
}
```

Exception :

```
Invalid property 'labelDTOS[0].labelItemDTOS[0]' of bean class 
[com.goitdev.datarender.command.domain.CreateTemplateCommand]: Illegal 
attempt to get property 'labelItemDTOS' threw exception; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid 
property 'labelDTOS[0].labelItemDTOS' of bean class 
[com.goitdev.datarender.command.domain.CreateTemplateCommand]: Could not 
instantiate property type [com.goitdev.datarender.dto.domain.LabelItemDTO] 
to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
com.goitdev.datarender.dto.domain.LabelItemDTO.<init>()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to perform GET mapping and print out value of your DTO, you can try this:
***In your controller method:***

```
...
model.addAttribute("labelDTO", new LabelDTO());
...
```

***In JSP***

```
...
<c:forEach items="${labelDTO.labelItemDTOS}" var="labelItemDTO">
<td>${labelItemDTO.value}<td>
<td>${labelItemDTO.placeHolder}<td>
<td>${labelItemDTO.newValue}<td>
</c:forEach>
...
```

Or ***for POST*** [***see this question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498216/how-to-save-many-objects-in-a-spring-formform) possible the same issue.